# Keep the middle words in a phrase separated by dashes in R using gsub

Tags: r, gsub

I have the following:

```
x <- c("Sao Paulo - Paulista - SP", "Minas Gerais - Mineiro - MG", "Rio de Janeiro - Carioca -RJ")
```

I want to keep "Paulista", "Mineiro", "Carioca"

I'm trying gsub like

```
y <- gsub("\\$-*","",x)
```

but is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do this with a single call to `sub`:

```
x <- c(" Sao Paulo - Paulista - SP",
       "Minas Gerais - Mineiro - MG",
       "Rio de Janeiro - Carioca -RJ")

sub("^.*-\\s+(.*?)\\s+-.*$", "\\1", x)
[1] "Paulista" "Mineiro"  "Carioca"
```

The idea is to capture whatever occurs in between the two dashes in each location.

```
^.*-\\s+   from the start, consume everything up to and including the first dash
(.*?)      then match and capture everything up until the second dash
\\s+-.*$   consume everything after and including the second dash
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked. can you explain tome what you've done?

Comment: @arabelo I tried to give an explanation for the regex.

Answer (score 3):

Two quick methods:

```
x<- c(" Sao Paulo - Paulista - SP", "Minas Gerais - Mineiro - MG", "Rio de Janeiro - Carioca -RJ")
```

This first is the standard `sub` solution; if there are strings without the hyphens, it will return the full strings unmodified.

```
trimws(sub("^[^-]*-([^-]*)-.*$", "\\1", x))
# [1] "Paulista" "Mineiro"  "Carioca"
```

Within the `sub`:

```
"^[^-]*-([^-]*)-.*$"
 ^                   beginning of each string, avoids mid-string matches
  [^-]*              matches 0 or more non-hyphen characters
       -             literal hyphen
        ([^-]*)      matches and stores 0 or more non-hyphen charactesr
               -     literal hyphen
                .*   0 or more of anything (incl hyphens)
                  5  end of each string

"\\1"                replace everything that matches with the stored substring
```

This next one works by splitting the string by `"-"` into a `list`, which is then indexed for the second element. If there are strings without hyphens, this will error with `subscript out of bounds`.

```
trimws(sapply(strsplit(x, "-"), `[[`, 2))
# [1] "Paulista" "Mineiro"  "Carioca"
```

Sample call to `strsplit`:

```
strsplit(x[[1]], "-")
# [[1]]
# [1] " Sao Paulo " " Paulista "  " SP"
```

... so the second element is `Paulista` (with extra leading/trailing whitespace). The surrounding `sapply` always grabs the second element (this is what errors when the string does not match).

Both solutions use `trimws` to reduce the leading and trailing whitespace.

Comment: Thanks! It worked. can you explain tome what you've done?